# Capture all Windows 7 Touch events, not just on my form when it has focus

Tags: c#, events, windows-7, touch, multi-touch

I have an application which has a form, but the fact that it has a form is irrelevant.

With this app, I need to listen to all Operating System level Touch events. Basically I need to capture that the screen has been touched no matter which form has focus, gather all the info like coordinates etc. and then do whatever with it.

I'll actually be sending it on to another app via a Windows Message but that's not relevant either. **I just need to know how to listen and capture ALL OS level touch + drag events etc.**

Answer (score 4):

You can read HID data directly, using [a Raw Input API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and to parse it by yourself.

In general:

1. Find Hids and store preparsed data.
2. Register for input events
3. On `WM_INPUT` event parse buffer using HID API functions and preparsed data.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx) explains the topic of keyboard/mouse event hooks.

It is a rather advanced subject however, filled with lots of low-level interop.  I'd avoid such a task and try to come up with a different solution for this.  What is your final goal with this application?

Comment: Thanks. I intend to listen for when a user touches/touches & moves on the screen and send that message to my other application enabling my other application to utilise more than 2 points of touch (hardware permitting of course).

Comment: You can actually eliminate the 2nd application if you wish.  The first application could hook into keyboard/mouse events.